# connecting to internal webserver on specific port

Tags: iis, web-server, router, port

We have the **BT broadband** forwarding on to an internal machine with an IIS web server running. Thats fine, it goes to the sharepoint app, so the outside world can see this app.

Thing is we need **another app** running (a MVC ASP.Net app) and I have set it to **:8080.**

Internally I can get to it fine, but not when I type the IP number.

**eg. 80.100.232.129:8080**

is this something I need to set on the broadband router or something with SBS or somewhere else?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You just need to setup your external 8080 to forward to your internal IP on 8080 as well, basically the same as you've done already.

Comment: @chopper3 @boymars thanks; yes got there but seems not to be working as yet. rule is set but still blocking!

Comment: I don't have a BT HH to hand (I actually work for BT but not on that product line!), perhaps 8080 is the remote management port - have a look in the management options.

Comment: ahh ok whats a good port number to choose?

Comment: currently looking at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: hmm, ok well its working on the intranet fine, so the port works and the firw=ewall setings on the box are ok -   8080 is on both port and host port, dunno if that makes a difference (ie on the from: and to: )

Comment: ok sorted now, interface isnt particular user friendly!!

Comment: totally agree, is it a white one or the new black one? The black one is miles better.

Comment: ha! its white background and you have this choose computer and under that a list of the different things to allow through. I had to select the custom rule; i thought creating the rule was actually adding to the list on the computer doh..

Comment: don't worry about it, they're just not user friendly - ah well at least you got there.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you're already port forwarding traffic to IIS on port 80. you simply need to add a rule to forward 8080 to the internal server in your router's NAT/port-forwarding options.

this will make it available to the outside world.